# Wpf datagrid clears multiple selection on right mouse click

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-4.5

I am implementing a `ContextMenu` on a `WPF DataGrid` at the right click of the mouse on the rowheader.

However, if I have multiple rows selected, the right mouse click will cause only the clicked row to become selected.

How can I prevent that? I want to implement commands on the ContextMenu that will work on all selected items.